# Azure web app kudu deployments C# 6

Tags: azure, continuous-integration, azure-web-app-service, c#-6.0, kudu

I have asp.mvc applicatioin on bitbucket GIT. I want to use azure auto deploy, but I cannot becouse azure build fails on C#6 feature ?.. Is there any option to enable C# on azure build?

I find https://github.com/KuduApps/CSharp6Web, but this I cannot use.

Comment: See this for a work around: https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/issues/1659

Answer (score 0):

In the Azure portal, add an **app setting** called **MSBUILD_PATH** for the web app, and set its value to:

```
%ProgramFiles(x86)%\MSBuild\14.0\Bin\MSBuild.exe
```

This will enable C# 6 until Microsoft changes the default MSBuild version for Azure web apps.